# Appropriate Prerequisites for Studying Fractal Geomerty by Kenneth Falconer

Tags: reference-request, fractals

Could anyone who has studied Fractal Geometry: Mathematical Foundations and Applications by Kenneth Falconer describe what the necessary prerequisites are for understanding the book completely? I have studied analysis up to the first seven chapters of Baby Rudin, would that background be appropriate for this text? If not, could someone suggest another book on fractal geometry that would be more appropriate for my level? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're good to go - that text is targeted right at folks with your background. While measure theory is typically thought of as an important prerequisite for the serious study of fractal geometry, Falconer does an excellent job of explaining the basic and relevant ideas of measure theory in an intuitive way. Have fun!

Comment: I was little worried about starting with the book since I don't yet have measure theory in my mathematical toolkit. But from what you describe, it seems I can give the book a try. Thanks!